# How to access an inner object and its key/value pair in RactJS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I want to access the `title` inner object of the following object, which I am getting from WP REST API. But I am unable to reach the 'title'.

The REST API returns me an object, not an array because I am consuming an ID-based API endpoint i.e. `https://example.com/wp/wp-json/v2/procedures/7`.

The above gives me the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "date": "2023-06-08T11:39:59",
  "date_gmt": "2023-06-08T11:39:59",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "https://example.com/?post_type=procedure&#038;p=7"
  },
  "modified": "2023-06-09T05:45:45",
  "modified_gmt": "2023-06-09T05:45:45",
  "slug": "best-hydra-facial-treatment",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "procedure",
  "link": "https://example.com/procedure/best-hydra-facial-treatment/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Best Hydra Facial Treatment"
  },
  ...
  ...
}
```

I want to get the `rendered` key value from the `title` inner object. So I tried `proc.title.rendered` (proc is the object here). But this gives me the error `proc.title.rendered is not defined`.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What are you using to fetch these results?

Comment: `axios.get('https://example.com/....')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "id": 7,
  "date": "2023-06-08T11:39:59",
  "date_gmt": "2023-06-08T11:39:59",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "https://example.com/?post_type=procedure&#038;p=7"
  },
  "modified": "2023-06-09T05:45:45",
  "modified_gmt": "2023-06-09T05:45:45",
  "slug": "best-hydra-facial-treatment",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "procedure",
  "link": "https://example.com/procedure/best-hydra-facial-treatment/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Best Hydra Facial Treatment"
  }
}
console.log(data?.guid?.rendered)
console.log(data.title.rendered)
console.log(data?.title?.rendered)
```

above code is log "rendered key".
in case at your object, some sub object has `title obj` & `rendered key`. if some of them do not have the key, that can be error.

in that case, could you try ? in front of dot notation

```js
data?.title?.rendered
```

[example](https://replit.com/@yewinag/MedicalTrivialConfig#package.json)

Comment: Thank you! The solution worked like a charm. However, would you please explain what exactly happened here?

Comment: docs is here [optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It means if it has no the key, will returns `undefined`. [link](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining) The optional chaining ?. stops the evaluation if the value before ?. is undefined or null and returns undefined.